# Robo3T Does not show the database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, robo3t

[image]

I can connect to a MongoDB Atlas replica set but it has no database.

[image]

When I click the master node, it shows a new shell

[image]

And I can find the objects with `db.getCollection('aCollection').find()`

How can I show/add the database in the left pane?

ps. I was using Robo3T 1.3.1

Comment: I think I have found a workaround.
Doing `Create Database` with the database name adds the database in the left panel and seems not to break anything.
I am not sure it's okay to do this though.

Comment: It might need to adjust the permission to allow list databases if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

IMO this is a issue of insufficient privileges on the user account used to log in to ROBO3T and access MongoDB. You can follow this [link](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1410). It points to a similar issue on Robo3Ts Github. You can use MongoDB Compass to connect to remote/Atlas MongoDB instances too. It is much user friendly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried MongoDB Compass and it does show the collection. However, I don't like to use that since I am more familiar with Robo3T and don't want to use an Electron based app. Robo3T is nearly working except for the collection in the left pane so I want to find the way.

Comment: @Kennyhyun did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @ahmed-saeed, as [the comment I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56197307/robo3t-does-not-show-the-database/56197881?noredirect=1#comment99030656_56197307) just found a workaround. and have not tried later versions since then.

Comment: I had this same issue, and the issue with Robo 3T not showing the database was an issue with the permission given to the account used to login to the database. I needed to give readWrite ANY database for it it to show the databases.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This worked for me. Just set MongoDB Roles to atlasAdmin@admin.